# How do we convert the Nested Lists in Microsoft Word DOCX file to HTML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<w:p w:rsidR="008845A9" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="008845A9" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="001207E2" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="001207E2" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>First Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Second Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Third Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="2"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Third Item – One</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="2"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Third Item </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>–</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Two</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="006551A3" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="3"/>
                <w:numId w:val="6"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Sample Item </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="00554D9D" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>A</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00554D9D" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="3"/>
                <w:numId w:val="6"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Sample Item B</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Fo</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="00565721" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>u</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>rth Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Hi,this is the part of the code of XML file of the Microsoft Word DOCX and these are the lists are nested like the shown above.

```
1.First Item
2.Second Item
3.Third Item
    i.Third Item – One
    ii.Third Item – Two
       a.Sample Item A
       b.Sample Item B
4.Fourth Item
```

Instead of this figure i get the result like;

```
•First Item
•Second Item
•Third Item
•Third Item – One
•Third Item – Two
•Sample Item A
•Sample Item B
•Fourth Item
```

And this was my solution in XSLT to fix this problem by using `<ul>` and `<li>` but i guess i need something different to implement here. I dont know what to do, the rest is fine i can handle the table parts etc.But the nested lists are problem now.

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="w:p">
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Title']">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </h1>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Description']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:numPr">
                        <ul>
                            <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/></li>
                        </ul>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <p>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                        </p>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Claim']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:spacing[@w:line='360']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Heading']">
                <h2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </h2>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*I  found the solution *

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="w:p">
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Title']">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </h1>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Description']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl[@w:val='1']">
                        <ul>
                            <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/></li>
                        </ul>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl[@w:val='2']">
                        <ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl[@w:val='3']">
                        <ul>
                            <ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <p>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                        </p>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Claim']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:spacing[@w:line='360']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='AppBody-Heading']">
                <h2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                </h2>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*But this is not an automatic solution.For example,If there is another layer in different document,this is not going to work.

How do we select the numbers "1" to ".." automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer to this question buried within

[XSLT transformation of boolean expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301195/xslt-transformation-of-boolean-expressions/34308637#34308637)

but since there's a lot of noise around it there, I'll extract the relevant part.

Given a sequence of elements with level numbers:

```
<a level="1"/>
<b level="2"/>
<c level="3"/>
<d level="3"/>
<e level="2"/>
```

we can turn them into a tree structure

```
<a><b><c/><d/></b><e/></a>
```

using recursive grouping as follows. We write a template that does one level of grouping, and then calls itself recursively to do the next level:

```
<xsl:template name="grouping">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:if test="exists($input)">
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="$input[1]/@level"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" 
                        group-starting-with="*[@level=$level]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="grouping">
           <xsl:with-param name="input" 
                           select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

That's using XSLT 2.0. A solution using XSLT 1.0 is going to be much, much harder.

Of course your input has a lot of M$ noise compared with my little sample. But the structure of the problem is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try to use this aproach in my code and lets see if it is gonna work or not.By the way why do you think that there are a lot noise here ?

Comment: Not "here", but "there" - at the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301195/xslt-transformation-of-boolean-expressions/34308637#34308637.